# Grading Scale in Java

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have a Java assignment to make a grading scale like the one below.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class gradeSelection {
   public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter Score: ");
   double score = input.nextDouble();
   if (score >= 90) {
        System.out.println("Your score is " + score + " which is an A");
        if ((score < 90) && (score >= 80)){
            System.out.println("Your score is " + score + " which is an B");
            if ((score < 80) && (score >= 70)){
                System.out.println("Your score is " + score + " which is an C");
                if ((score < 70) && (score >= 60)){
                    System.out.println("Your score is " + score + " which is an D");
                    if (score < 60){
                        System.out.println("Your score is " + score + " which is an E");
                    }//endif
                }//endif    
            }//endif
        }//endif
    }//endif
}
}
```

I can get it to work in Eclipse but it will terminate after I input a number. What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Nothing get printed ??

Comment: I think you want to use `else if` not nested `if`s. It is impossible to print B, C, D, F because it will only go in the first `if` statement if your score is above 90.

Comment: Also another note I recommend to not use [lower camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for your class names, it should be `GradeSelection` not `gradeSelection`.

Comment: @BigRabbit Not really, because (a) almost every closing brace closes an if, and (b) comments should provide *context*, not reflect syntax.

Comment: @BigRabbit Unconstructive? I see; what would I know about educating people about, and thinking about code, right? Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `if` and `else if`, because if the first condition doesn't match it will exit and will not reach the nested (the other) conditions:

Try to change it like:

```
if (score >= 90) {
    System.out.println("Your score is " + score + " which is an A");
} else if (score >= 80){
    System.out.println("Your score is " + score + " which is an B");
}//and so on
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to check if it's less than 90, because you checked it in the previous if.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, if the input is not bigger than 90, then nothing is printed.
Use `else if`s rather than this approach.